# Скругление углов линейного графика Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Час добрый
Подскажите, пожалуйста, варианты закругления острых углов линейного графика, выведенного при помощи `matplotlib`

Код и график прикреплю ниже

Нужно чтобы не было острых углов, как на графике ниже

```py
def create_cpm_diagram():
    mounts = ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Агуст', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь']
    counter = [2604.14, 2567.56, 2950.61, 2225.23, 1867.68, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    matplotlib.use('Agg')
    plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 8))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 8))
    for label in (ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
        label.set_fontsize(15)
    plt.plot(mounts, counter, marker='o', markersize=7, color='#2d79bd')

    plt.savefig('cpm_diagram.png')
```

[image: График с кода]

Ниже пример графика с кругленными краями, но слишком большими отступами между вершинами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нижний график реализован следующим кодом:

```py
matplotlib.use('Agg')

x = np.array(mounts)
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
y = np.array(counter)

x_sm = np.array(x)
y_sm = np.array(y)
X_Y_Spline = make_interp_spline(x_sm, y_sm)

X_ = np.linspace(x_sm.min(), x_sm.max(), 5000)
Y_ = X_Y_Spline(X_)

plt.plot(X_, Y_)
```

Если подскажите как уменьшить разрыв между вершинами и заменить названия в строке Х на месяца, то такой вариант тоже будет более чем рабочим

В идеале получить что-то похожее на подобные плавные переходы между вершинами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну со сплайнами всегда так, на то они и сплайны. У вас чрезвычайно мало входных данных для построения более плавного и точного графика. Вы можете поменять степень сплайна явным образом (по умолчанию она 3, кубическая) - я для примера показал второй график с квадратичной. ну а названия меток задать очень просто:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline
import numpy as np

months = ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Агуст', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь']
counter = [2604.14, 2567.56, 2950.61, 2225.23, 1867.68, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

spline_2 = make_interp_spline(range(len(months)), counter, k=2) # квадрат
spline_3 = make_interp_spline(range(len(months)), counter, k=3) # куб

newx_2 = np.linspace(0, len(months), 200)
newy_2 = spline_2(newx_2)

newx_3 = np.linspace(0, len(months), 200)
newy_3 = spline_3(newx_3)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 6))

for label in (ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
    label.set_fontsize(10)
# задаем подписи меток по оси x
ax.set_xticks(range(len(months)))
ax.set_xticklabels(months)

plt.plot(newx_2, newy_2, color='red')
plt.plot(newx_3, newy_3, color='green')
plt.savefig('cpm_diagram.png')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]